# Google Analytics showing broken landing and exit pages related to my YouTube channel

Tags: google-analytics, landing-page, exit-pages

I am trying to understand why Google Analytics is showing me landing and exit pages from my site which are the same, and broken.  I don't understand how users are coming to these pages that seem to have part of the link from my YouTube account. Here is what I am seeing  my Google Analytics exit pages for russlaw.co.uk

[image]

This is the link to my youtube account: https://www.youtube.com/user/russandnela

As you can see, GA has this part on the end `/user/russandnela`, but I cant workout why people would be hitting my site via this incomplete part of a url.
Any help would be welcome. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to check all your internal links, maybe those urls are linked somewhere?
You could use screaming frog for example, its free and a nice multi tool ;-)